Need to find which Angular template is causing an error
I'm in the process of upgrading an app from Angular 8.x to 9.x (first step towards upgrading to latest), using ng update. After the update, I'm seeing the following when starting the app:
[ng] ERROR in Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "option". Template variables are read-only.
[ng]     at _AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (/Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8923:31)
[ng]     at PropertyWrite.visit (/Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7795:28)
[ng]     at convertActionBinding (/Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8524:49)
[ng]     at prepareEventListenerParameters (/Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17703:27)
[ng]     at Object.params (/Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18828:24)
[ng]     at /Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18599:94
[ng]     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
[ng]     at /Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18599:60
[ng]     at /Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17860:87
[ng]     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
[ng]     at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (/Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17860:60)
[ng]     at /Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18401:60
[ng]     at /Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17838:81
[ng]     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
[ng]     at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (/Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17838:37)
[ng]     at /Users/demami/Projects/claimocity-mobile/mobile-ui/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18401:60

I've search through the templates and found and fixed other places assigning to template variables, but can't find the one causing this error. Is there a way to find the specific template file causing this error?
In case it matters, I'm serving using ionic serve rather than ng serve.

My answer depends on the size of the project, that being said if you have fewer templates you can comment out half of them (binary search method) and then you can try to build it again.

I considered that, but there are 160+ templates. I was hoping for a command flag to add, or something like that.

You have in "any html" some like
<htmlTag #option></htmlTag>
//or
<app-component #option></app-component>

Here, #option create a template reference variable option.
A template reference variable is a "public variable" (only visible in .html), Sure you have in the .ts another variable also called option (or you are in .html some like option=...), and this makes the error. Change the template reference variable name (I suggest call it, e.g. #optionId) and replace in .html all the "option" by "optionId" and also if you're using ViewChild
//replace
@ViewChild('option') yourVariable!:ElementRef
//by
@ViewChild('optionId') yourVariable!:ElementRef

